# "Generations of pure-bloods, wizards all - more than *you* can say, I don't doubt!" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> "So!" said Gaunt triumphantly, as though he had just proved a complicated point beyond all possible dispute. "Don't you go talking to us as if we're dirt on your shoes! **Generations of pure-bloods, wizards all - more than *you* can say, I don't doubt!**"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-blood Prince</sub>

I don't quite understand the part in bold in this context. What does it say exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gaunt is claiming that the ministry wizard should give him more respect because all his family are pure blood wizards, for many generations.

He isn't speaking in complete sentences (he is uneducated and in-bred) but he exclaims,

> (My family is made of many) generations of pure-bloods. *All my ancestors were wizards* (no muggles or squibs). (There are more generations of pure-blood wizards) than you can say (of your family),  *I'm certain of this*.

Comment: I would think that the "more" in this case doesn't necessarily mean more generations of pure-blood wizards, but that the claim to such ancestry is more than the visitor can claim.

Comment: Yes, clarified.

Answer (score 0):

"Generations of pure-bloods, wizards all" is appositive to "us". It's understood that it's a description that applies to "us"; we are generations of pure-bloods. James K implies that this is ungrammatical, but non-sentence appositive phrases are perfectly grammatical. "more than you can say, I don't doubt!" is then appositive of "Generations of pure-bloods, wizards all".